# Find all collections in mongodb with specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

There is more than 40 collections in database I am currently working on.
One of the major key in all the collections is "account".
I need to know all such collections where there is a field called "account".

Is there a query to get or a js script which prints all such collections?

In Oracle I was using :

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'account';
```

Any inputs is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is another issue regarding this. Few collections are using different naming conventions, like account_id or account or accountId or Account. Is there a way to do a regex on the column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following mongo script will print out all collection names where at least one document contains an `account` field.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    var count = db[collname].find({"account": {$exists: true}}).count();
    if (count > 0) {
      print(collname);
    }
})
```

Comment: This will find fields exactly with "account". How can we do regex of column name?