# Is there a way to find collection Name from a field name in Mongo DB Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo DB and NoSQL world. I am trying to find an equivalent of dba_tab_cols of Oracle in Mongo DB. My intention is, if I know a field name, I should be able to find out what all collections have that field by a query. Is it even possible in Mongo DB?

Comment: [Find all collections in mongodb with specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491473/find-all-collections-in-mongodb-with-specific-field)

Comment: The answer from @prasad_ is fully correct, however MongoDB does not work like you may know from relational databases. When you insert data into a collection which does not exist, then a new collection is created automatically. When you select a collection/field which does not exist then you simply get a `null` value. An error like `Collection does not exist` or `Invalid field name` does not exist in MongoDB.

Comment: In case you want to create collections with predefined structure and with constraints / validations on fields - use the optional [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). This allows validation during insert and update operations.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you are looking for collections with the field `name`:

```
var collections = db.getCollectionNames()
var matches = []
for (let coll of collections) {
    let result = db[coll].findOne({ name: { $exists: true }})
    if (result) matches.push(coll)
}

printjson(matches)
```

Note that this will include where the field exists and also includes even if the value is null. So, if you want to exclude those collections with field value as `null`, use the following filter:

```
let result = db[coll].findOne({ name: { $exists: true, $ne: null }})
```

For fields which contains a *substring* of the value you are looking for, use Regex. For example, if you are looking for collections with field names containing `name`, and this would match for field names "firstName", "lastName" and "name".

```
let result = db[coll].aggregate([
    { $project: { flds: { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }}}, 
    { $match: { "flds.k": /name/ }},
    { $limit: 1 }
]).hasNext()
```

**NOTE:**

- This runs from `mongo` shell.
- These scripts do *not* look for fields within nested objects and objects within arrays.
- These look for collections within the *current database* only. For searching in all databases, you can try:

```
var dbNames = db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true })["databases"].map(d => d.name)
for (let dbname of dbNames) {
    let collections = db.getSiblingDB(dbname).getCollectionNames()
    // ...
}
```